# Getting Customer Data From Order

Tags: orders, payment-gateway

I am getting the following error when trying to get customer data from the one step checkout to send to a custom payment gateway:

> ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to MYMODULE_Helper_Data::getContactData() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order, instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote given

This is called here:

> called in /var/www/vhosts/MYSITE/app/code/community/MYMODULE/Model/Method/Abstract.php on line 183 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/MYSITE/app/code/community/MYMODULE/Helper/Data.php on line 117

The module is still getting the required data, but this error is creating issues when users use developer mode.

Unsure what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your helper you may have forced the function getContactData parameters to be an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` but you are working with the quote `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` that is what the error means.
You have to change the parameter type with `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` in your helper function.

---

In the checkout onepage the quote is not converted yet to an order so any function used in the onepage may be compatible with the quote instance.

Comment: You're welcome. A precision for why you have this error only with developer mode only is that developer mode show all errors, it is the debuging tool for Magento. If you turn it off only PHP fatal error are shown.